# django object.filters.order_by() returns the same instance multiple times when the field i am ordering by is a "many to many"

Tags: django, django-models

Here is the problem: I have two models `Contact` and `Title`.

- **Contact** represent a person
- **Title** represent a job title

A person can have more than one job title and the two models are related through a many to many relation (see models below).

The issue is that for some reason when I make this query `contacts = Contact.objects.filter("some filter").order_by('title')` I get contacts with more than one title returned multiple times...because I am ordering by title and I guess django is confused on which title to use? I am losing my mind on how to fix it while keeping ordering by title.

```
class Title(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name_surname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    title = models.ManyToManyField(Title)
    ...
```

Comment: Given there are two titles, which of the titles should be selected? The one with the "smallest" id, or `title_name`, or something else?

Comment: I am querying for contacts so I want to get all contacts and I want to get all the titles they came with. Then I want to order by title but I agree that django doesn't know where to put someone that has two titles because he doesn't know which one to use for ordering...but how do i fix it? I don't really care which of the two is used

Comment: Found an answer (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because I am ordering by title and I guess django is confused on which title to use?

In essence you make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and thus for each item in the second table, it will retrieve a record.

If you want to order by the *minimum* title, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Contact.objects.filter(…).alias(
    min_title=Min('title')
).order_by('min_title')
```

or prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), we can annotate the items:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Contact.objects.filter(…).annotate(
    min_title=Min('title')
).order_by('min_title')
```

You can use `min_title=Min('title__title_name')` to order lexicographically by the name of the title.

If you want to enumerate over the related `title`s of all `Contact`s in an efficient manner, you can use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to load related items in *bulk* instead of one extra query *per* `Contact`:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Contact.objects.filter().alias(
    min_title=Min('title')
).order_by('min_title').prefetch_related('title')
```

Comment: Hey Willem, thanks for your reply! I Implemented your solution and it was actually working perfectly until I deployed my Django with Heroku and switched from SQlite to postgres...now it's giving me this error that I think has to do with the fact that I am ordering by "min_title" but it's not recognizing the alias. ```django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function min(uuid) does not exist
LINE 1: ..._id" = 1) GROUP BY "action_contact"."id" ORDER BY MIN("actio...```

Comment: `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @giaggi: hi, I think this is because PostgreSQL has no notion of a minimum of two uuids. Apparently you can define one however in postgreSQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641461/67579

Comment: @giaggi: you can furthermore also order by `min_title=Min('title__title_name')` to order on the *name* of the title, which will (normally) work.

Comment: Nice! This one did the trick! `Contact.objects.filter(
                        (Q(owner__isnull=True) | Q(owner=request.user))
                        ).alias(min_title=Min('title__title_name')).order_by('min_title')`